# How to configure Mutlilayer C# .Net Core Project for use of Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core

**The situation**

I'm working on a school project and I use Blazor (Server-Side) for the Frontend. I do have a business layer and a DataAcces Layer (both .Net Core Class Libraries). I'm using Code First to create an SQLite database.

**The problem/error**

I somehow get following messages when trying to execute `Add-Migration InitialCreate`:

**The warning**

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
> services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
> 'AddDbContext' was called with configuration, but the context type
> 'TemperBapesContext' only declares a parameterless constructor. This
> means that the configuration passed to 'AddDbContext' will never be
> used. If configuration is passed to 'AddDbContext', then
> 'TemperBapesContext' should declare a constructor that accepts a
> DbContextOptions and must pass it to the base
> constructor for DbContext.

**The error**

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
> provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring'
> method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider.
> If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
> accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and
> passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

**Project Architecture and Description**

The Startup project is my Blazor application.

[image: project architecture]

My **appsettings.json** contains the ConnectionString to the database:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLite": "Data Source=L:\\M183\\m183\\project\\SQLite\\TemperBapesDB.db;"
  }
```

My **Startup.cs** ConfigureServices() looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddBussinesLayer(Configuration);
}
```

The **SetupExtensions.cs** on Business Level looks like this:

```
public static void AddBussinesLayer(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddDataAccess(configuration);
}
```

The **SetupExtensions.cs** on DataAccess Level looks like this:

```
public static void AddDataAccess(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddDbContext<TemperBapesContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLite")));
}
```

**NuGet-Packages Installed**

Blazor project:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Business Layer:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions

DataAccess Layer:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Comment: @devNull Not exactly but Cem.S has answered my question below.

Comment: not sure how that doesn't answer it, since it's the same error and same answer

Comment: Oh I actually looked at the post because your link points to the question and not the answer. You're able to get the link of answers directly. But thank you as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TemperBapesContext : DbContext
{
    // Your DbSets 

    // This constructor is needed
    public TemperBapesContext(DbContextOptions<TemperBapesContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

You need to add a constructor where `DbContextOptions` can be injected

Comment: Omg I feel so embarrassed right now. I've searched for a solution everywhere but there. Thanks a lot! Already worked with this kind of projects I just forgot a lot of things again.